# Printing the elements of an ArrayList

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Prog1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the value:");
        Integer v = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter number of elements:");
        int n = in.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList(Prog1.duplica(v, n));

        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(a.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> duplica(Integer v, int n) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a.set(i, v);
        }

        return a;
    }

}
```

This method should ask for a integer value and for the number of elements cointaned in the arraylist and then it should print them. For example if the user inserts "5" and "4" it should print "5 5 5 5". The program does ask the user the two numbers but then it gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:472)
    at Prog1.duplica(Prog1.java:20)
    at Prog1.main(Prog1.java:11)
```

Comment: Use `a.add(v)` rather than `a.set()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is IndexOutOfBoundsException Thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516592/why-is-indexoutofboundsexception-thrown)

Comment: `set` ***replaces*** an element at a given index with the new one you provide. This means that the list must be filled before using that method. If you simply need to add elements to the list, use `add` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the `set` method to add items to an empty list. `set` is supposed to replace an already-existing value at a specified index. Since your list is empty, there is no value to replace, resulting in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while trying to access the first element.

Use `add` instead:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  a.add(v);
}
```